# Do I really need Python on my Linux system (specifically my LFS one)?

Tags: python, linux, linux-from-scratch

I'm building an LFS system and I'm hoping to deploy the Linux distro I build for a very specific purpose. I won't say what the purpose is, but I purposefully left out Python, among some other packages, in the hopes that they weren't actually necessities (which, for this distro's purpose, they are not), in the build process. But lo and behold,  I went to compile glibc as chroot, and got these errors...

```
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: gawk bison python
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

I can kind of understand gawk and bison, but do I REALLY need Python? Are there really important Linux programs built in Python? I like Python, but I'm really hoping to go without for this distribution, and if I HAD to install it, then I planned to remove it before deploying it to save on file space. The same question applies to Perl.

Comment: Python is needed to compile glibc. If you want to compile glibc on the target system, you need python. If you compile in a chroot on a different system and then install on target system, you don't. As mentioned in the text, read glibc's INSTALL doc.

Comment: It sounds like you left out Python etc. in the Temporary System (Ch. 5). You shouldn't do that because that whole purpose is to build a minimal tool chain. You can *probably* skip some packages in Ch. 6 to meet your purposes for the final system. While `/tools` is available those requirements will met in chroot. Once the build is complete and `/tools` is unavailable, you'll find out pretty quick in testing if anything you skipped was absolutely required to run something you do want.